# Installed MAMP. PHP Issue: String quotes wrongfully display when echoing

Tags: php, mamp, quotes

When I selected 5.6.10, I typed the code:

```
echo "test";
```

It displays:

```
"test"
```

When I selected 5.5.26, I typed the same code:

```
 echo "test";
```

It displays:

```
 â€œtestâ€
```

Either way, I just want it to display:

```
test
```

Comment: character set issue, and your quotes are really "smart quotes" (aka moronic quotes). typographic "6's and 9's".

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem with databases where the inbound string was utf8 and the db was operating on latin-1. In this case your browser appears to be defaulting to latin-1 for it's text stream and php appears to be sending in utf-8. Do you have a header mismatch perhaps?